# Cloud Firestore model organization with small entities

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I've been catching up on firebase firestore for a week, but I have a question in the back of my head: let's say I want to create an Android app, a todo list.

## Context

To give some context, in my app the most used entity will be the `Task` object, which contains the text the user typed in, the user id, and maybe a flag, indicating whether the task is completed.

One task can also belong to one user-defined category, (object `Category`), which just has a title.

My firestore tree structure would ideally look like this, with 2 root-level collections

[image: Firebase Structure]

## Question

The issue with this model is that my data is really small in size, and possibly extremely large in number (A user may produce lots of different tasks with a short text).

By doing so, I would get billed for a lot of writes and a few reads. (i.e. the user creates the tasks, edits the title, marks it as completed, but reads just happen when another client modifies a task, and firestore is optimized for reads over writes)

Therefore, if the user has 100 tasks, having 100 documents with just a couple of fields in them looks just wrong. 
In firestore tutorials a document typically holds at least a dozen of fields. To comparison, my small documents have to be written a lot of times, but they are tiny, and the technology I'm using feels overkilled for this type of scenario.

Plus, I don't get how I should reference categories from tasks.
If each task has a category, then every read to a single task wouldn't be complete without its category counterpart, and this would imply reading twice as much as documents.

To fix this, I also thought about embedding the category directly inside the actual task, but then if the user changes/deletes a category I'd have to perform a batch write to all my tasks to edit/remove the demoralized data leftovers.

So my final questions would be: is cloud firestore right for this kind of light-data but heavy-numbered project? Is my model the optimal one? And, am I liking tasks with categories in the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's okay to have a small document size. It is easier to query tasks if they have their own documents. Having a separate document for each task adds scalability to your project if you ever need to add fields to your `Task` object (timestamp, etc...) when you want your users to be able to sort and query tasks in different ways (most-recent tasks, completed tasks, etc...).

To reference the category in your task object, you can just include a `category` field in your task object. This way, you can query tasks by category using `tasksRef.whereEqualTo("category", "miscellaneous")`.

Also, if your users will only be able to view their own tasks/categories, it might be better to use subcollections in your user document:

```
- users (collection)
  |
  - <userId> (document)
    | 
    - tasks (collection)
      |
      - <taskId> (document)
```

This way, you don't have to query within a large `tasks` collection from *all* of your users when one user is only concerned about his/her tasks. Also, by doing it this way, you don't have to include the `userId` field in your `Task` object.